# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined phaser 3 platformer game

Tags: html, undefined, addition, phaser-framework

```
physics: {
            defult: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity:{y:300},
                debug: false
            }
        },
    }

        function create() {
        
        platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        platforms.add.image(200,585,'platforms');
```

Whenever I run this code I get the error that adds is `undefined`. I am coding in phaser 3.

```
var config = {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            // changing width and height of game screen to fit any device that it is accessed on.
            width: window.innerWidth*window.devicePixelRatio,
            height: window.innerHeight*window.devicePixelRatio,
            physics: {
                defult: 'arcade',
                arcade: {
                    gravity:{y:300},
                    debug: false
                }
            },
            scene:{
                preload: preload,
                create: create,
                update: update,
            },
        };
```

Comment: Where and how do you set the physics in your config ? Can you include the complete config and how it is used ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `platforms` and use the `create()` function on the next line.
Replace the two lines where you created `platforms` and added the image with:

```
const platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
platforms.create(200, 585, 'platforms');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you spelled it(defult keyword) wrong!!

```
// Incorrect code
var config = {
  physics: {
      defult: 'arcade', // Your mistake!! defult!?? or default ??
      arcade: {
          gravity:{y:300},
          debug: false
      }
  },
}


// correct code
var config = {
  physics: {
      default: 'arcade',
      arcade: {
          gravity:{y:300},
          debug: false
      }
  },
}
```